# parsing xliff file using lxml library

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, xliff

I'm not able to parse this xliff fragment:

```
<source>text1 <g id="1">text2</g> text3 <x id="2"/><x id="3"/>text4</source>
```

I would like to have a iterative method which runs on the source tag and fill something like

```
parsed_source[0]='text1'
parsed_source[1]='<g id="1">text2</g>'
parsed_source[2]='text3'
parsed_source[3]='<x id="2"/>'
parsed_source[4]='<x id="3"/>'
parsed_source[5]='text4'
```

So that I can iterate again on the xml fragment [1], [3] and [4] if needed...

Using `lxml` for example:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.iterparse('aFile.xlf')
for action, elem in tree:
    print("%s: %s %s" % (action, elem.tag, elem.text))
```

I get something similar to:

```
end: source text1
end: g text2
end: x None
end: x None
```

And I'm not able to parse `text3` and `text4`...How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the `tail` property (the text following the element) into account. Read about it here: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text.

The following snippet (a slight modification of your code) demonstrates it:

```
from lxml import etree
 
tree = etree.iterparse('aFile.xlf')
for action, elem in tree:
    print("%s: %s %s %s" % (action, elem.tag, elem.text, elem.tail))
```

Output:

```
end: g text2  text3 
end: x None None
end: x None text4
end: source text1  None
```